# Resolve dependencies for authentication event handler through DI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I use JWT bearer tokens to protect my ASP.NET Core 2.1 web API. During `ConfigureServices`, I setup the authentication, and tie in a `JwtBeaererEvents` object via options for additional processing. I'd like this object to be part of the DI container but I'm not sure how to do that. For now, I have to create instances and pass it through the constructor (anti-pattern). But this is going to create a chicken and an egg scenario:

```
/* HACK */
var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();

services.AddAuthentication(opts =>
{
    opts.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(opts =>
{                
    opts.Audience = "https://foobar.com/FooAPI";
    opts.Authority = Constants.AuthEndpointPrefix + "common/";
    opts.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters { ValidateIssuer = false };

    /* I would like JwtBearerEvents to be part of the 
       DI container and request the Logger and AppInsights 
       Dependency through the ctor 
    */
    opts.Events = new 
       JwtBearerEvents(
          LoggerFactory.CreateLogger<JwtBearerEvents>(),
          sp.GetService<TelemetryClient>() 
       );  
    });
```

Comment: I would even say that this will not work, or if it currently works, it might break in the future. This is because `TelemetryClient` is registered as [singleton](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/blob/17cc5de23ba58872650f7f2c4eaf0f0f2e47a823/src/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore/Extensions/ApplicationInsightsExtensions.cs#L184), but each `ServiceProvider` instance will get its own set of singleton instances. So your `JwtBearerEvents` will get a different instance. This might cause trouble, now, or in the future (when the `TelemetryClient` impl changes).

Comment: @Kirk OPs hack might cause problems. Your suggested aproach is the right way to go forward.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The authentication system in ASP.NET Core 2 supports this natively using the [`EventsType` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.authenticationschemeoptions.eventstype?view=aspnetcore-2.1) of the authentication scheme options:

```
services.AddTransient<MyJwtBearerEvents>();
services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.EventsType = typeof(MyJwtBearerEvents);
    });
```

If this property is set, then the events instance will get resolved when the authentication scheme is being initialized at the beginning of the request.

Apart from this, note that you could also access the `HttpContext` instance that gets passed as part of the event contexts, and use the service locator pattern to resolve services inside of your event handlers. While using the service locator is generally not the best idea, it can give you a bit more flexibility in this case, if you require some dependencies just for a particular event type.

Comment: That looks perfect. Thanks.

Comment: Using this in asp.net core 2.2.  Thanks @poke

Comment: @poke Is ‘AddTransient’ the correct DI option for EventsType?

Comment: @user2966445 You rarely do anything wrong when using transient. The events type is likely consumed within the request scope but unless you need to persist some state (which you probably shouldn’t do in the events implementation) there is nothing wrong with sticking to transient.