# ASP.Net Core OIDC how to Identify New Sign-In

Tags: openid-connect, asp.net-core-3.1

I have an ASP.Net Core MVC Application configured to authenticate using OIDC, as follows:

```
.AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
  options.Authority = appSettings.OIDCAuthority;
  options.ClientId = appSettings.OIDCClientId;
  options.ClientSecret = appSettings.OIDCClientSecret;
  options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
  options.Scope.Add("profile");
  options.SaveTokens = true;
  options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
  {
    OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) =>
    {
      return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.CompletedTask;
    },
    OnTokenResponseReceived = (context) =>
    {
      return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

I have hooked in to the `OnTokenResponseReceived` and the `OnAuthorizationCodeReceived` events in the hope of being able to identify the user that has just been signed in by the OIDC provider.

But in both of those events, the `context.HttpContext.User` shows as unauthenticated and I am not able to identify the now-logged-in user.

**How should I go about identifying a user who has just been signed in to my application by the external OIDC identity provider?**

Comment: Ok I've figured out that I need to use the `context.TokenEndpointResponse.IdToken` property of the `OnTokenReponseReceived` event.  This leads to another question though...can I trigger a Controller Action from this event handler?  I need to write a new login history record to the database, and fire off a SignalR method from this event.  All this requires DI Services to be injected.  Am I in the right place to do this kind of thing?  Or should I be looking to try to override the `/signin-oidc` callback with my own controller method instead?

Comment: Ok It seems I found my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52468816 I can implement a custom EventsType that can handle DI.