# How to use AuthenticationSchemeOptions.Events or AuthenticationSchemeOptionsEventsType?

Tags: asp.net-core

Ok, so as per usual, MSDN is now an automatically generated blob of useless documents, so maybe the developers lurk around here and can explain this to me.

I created a custom Authentication scheme based off of the `AuthenticationHandler<TOptions>` base class.  I have two questions regarding this:

1. How do I define the type to use in `AuthenticationSchemeOptions.EventsType` in order to consume authentication-related events?
2. If the loggerFactory object a required object?  Can't I just pass null to it?  I want to control my output.  I guess I could test this one myself.  If you want to answer, go ahead, otherwise I'll test it at some point.

But what I have no clue whatsoever is for question 1.  I see the class JwtBearerEvents as a sample, but I have no idea if I should be creating one exactly like that, or in general, how does this event system works at all????  I am utterly confused.

Thank you.

P. S.:  I don't think it is important, but just so you know, the custom authentication handler basically validates a JWT created by a federated API server whose signing keys can be queried to verify signature.  So basically it is a handler that makes a web request (then caches the keys) and uses those keys to validate the token and extract the claim data of interest, finally creating a ClaimsPrincipal user out of said claims.

Comment: Could [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52468816/resolve-dependencies-for-authentication-event-handler-through-di) meet your needs?

Comment: Don't think so.  My time is up, so I'll start experimenting and if I have time I'll come and post my findings.  Basically there's zero documentation about how this is done for an arbitrary implementation.